# How to change Background color and text color of Today's date in a CalendarView in Android?

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I'm trying to Give a grey Circular Background and dark grey text color to Today's date on CalendarView.
[image: Here]

Here I want to achieve the Theme that is put on 28. The style set for 20 is the date that User Selects.

I tried using selector with following combination `android:state_active="true" android:state_enabled="true"` and other combinations by replacing `state_active` with other boolean states. None of tgese changed the Theme. Here's a full code of the Selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/calendar_text_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_activated="false" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/calendar_selected_text_color" android:state_activated="true" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey_20" android:state_active="true" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>

<style name="CalendarView.DateAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:lineHeight">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_calendar_date</item>
    </style>
```

And I'm setting this style to CalendarView like this `android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalendarView.DateAppearance"`

I'm unable to figure out two things here -

1. Set Font color for Today's date.
2. Set Grey Circular background to Today's date

Answer (score 0):

Try to create and set a style like this:

```
<style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="yourAppBase">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/white</item>  // color of date selected.
</style>
```

Then set theme in the .xml:

```
<CalendarView
   android:id="@+id/calendarView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom" />
```

Hope it does the job for you.